# localStorage in Angularjs share between tabs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

Currently I am using $window.sessionStorage.token, so if user refresh the Page it maintains its session without losing any data. But now I want to open in different tab, but it is asking me to login again. After doing some research I found out that I have to use the localStorage.

Problem Question -

1) How would I share session between tabs using local Storage?
2) Is there another approach to this problem?

I have checked most of the post out there and does not give good understanding. If anyone can help with understanding this with basic example would be great and much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to replace `sessionStorage` with `localStorage`?  Both uses the same [storage API](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#storage).

Comment: I did not try. But it worked. Feel so stupid. I got side track with angular-local-storage. Thanks

Comment: If you're accessing through other tabs, you should use localStorage using sessionStorage access only in the same tab.. but i wonder why you must show to other tab while using angularJS?

Comment: @DatzMe you mean to say I should avoid doing that in Angularjs? as it will lose its meaning of being single page application ?. Do you mind explaining in detail ?

Comment: It depends on your purpose of doing it.. Im using angularJS actually but don't have times to use it to view in other tab.. Well it depends on the purpose or in the scenario of using it...

Comment: @DatzMe hmm you are right. It depends on the purpose and scenario and here I might be over thinking from a Developer Perspective.

Comment: :) Developers always think what is best for the users not for the developer .. :) so if you think it is best then do it.. :) but the topic is all about sessionStorage and localStorage :) will if that so you will use localStorage but the consequences is that the user must log out because localStorage still available in a period of time unlike sessionStorage upon closing the browser or tabs it will gone..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a service to inject each controller or the $rootScope for unified access. I am doing the same thing with an angular app. Here is my version to get you started. Authutils service you see used in he code is an implementation of Stanford Javascript Crypto Library at http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/ to add a layer of security to the stored resources since they are easily visible with browser debugging tools:

```
angular.module('myApp').service('Dataservice', [
'Authutils',
function Dataservice(Authutils) {
    var _test = [1, 2, 3];

    var hasStorage = function() {
        if (Modernizr.localstorage) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    };

    var _get = function(key, make, init_data) {
        var out = [];
        var create = typeof make !== "undefined" ? make : false;
        var data = typeof init_data !== "undefined" ? init_data : false;

        if (hasStorage()) {
            var sval = localStorage.getItem(key);
            if (!!sval) {
                try {
                    sval = Authutils.decrypt(sval);
                    out = JSON.parse(sval);
                } catch (e) {

                }
            } else {
                if (create) {
                    if (data) {
                        data = Authutils.encrypt(data);
                        _set(key, data);
                    } else {
                        _set(key, []);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return out;
    };

    var _set = function(key, value) {
        if (hasStorage()) {
            var subject = JSON.stringify(value);
            localStorage.setItem(key, Authutils.encrypt(subject));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };

    var _drop = function(key) {
        if (hasStorage()) {
            localStorage.removeItem(key);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };

    var _nuke = function() {
        if (hasStorage()) {
            localStorage.clear();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };

    var _push = function(key, value) {
        var out = [];
        if (hasStorage()) {
            var current = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
            if (!!current) {
                current.push(value);
                _set(key, current);
            }
        }
        return out;
    };

    return {
        get: function(key, make, init_data) {
            return _get(key, make, init_data);
        },
        set: function(key, value) {
            _set(key, value);
        },
        push: function(key, value) {
            _push(key, value);
        },
        trash: function(key) {
            _cut(key);
        },
        nuke: function() {
            _nuke();
        },
        test: function() {
            return _test;
        }
    };
  }
]);
```

Comment: Very nice :). Do you mind creating a Plunker? so for starters like us have better understanding. Thanks for your answer